# The default output of the function. Solidity

Tags: solidity, truffle

This is simple smart contract for election of two candidates :

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract Election {
    //Model a candidate
    struct Candidate{
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint voteCount;
    }
    //Store Candidates
    //Fetch Candidate
    mapping(uint=>Candidate)public candidates;
    //Store Candidates Count
    uint public candidateCount;
    function election()public{
        addCandidate("Donald Trump");
        addCandidate("Barak Obama");
    }

    function addCandidate(string memory _name)private{
        candidateCount++;
        candidates[candidateCount] = Candidate(candidateCount,_name,0);
    }
}
```

Why the output is the default output ? Is the value that i'm passing is invalid ?

[image]

Comment: Is this a constructor 'election()'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to make a constructor, which add the candidates, then your constructor syntax `election()` is wrong. Change it into the following

```
constructor()public{
    addCandidate("Donald Trump");
    addCandidate("Barak Obama");
}
```

This constructor will be invoked when you deploy your contract, thus adding the two candidates.

Comment: I acctually just changed in my code the 'election' to 'Election'. At first i used capital letter, just my VScode showed me the error like: Functions are not allowed to have the same name as the contract. If you intend this to be a constructor, use "constructor(...) { ... }" to define it.
This declaration shadows an existing declaration.

Comment: So i changed to small 'election'

Comment: That Cause the default output

Comment: But i tried your method too, making a constructor instead of a function Election, and it work as well. Do u know why ?

Comment: The syntax for making constructor is changed to this.

Comment: I mean, as i know constructor and function are different things isn't it ? why it would behave same(same output) if we declare it as constructor or as a fucntion